# Get all Hive table/database creation/deletion details (audit logs)

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-hive

Lets say I have a database - project . I created a table named tab1 and then later tab2 . Now I dropped the table tab1.

Where do I look for the logs that says I have dropped the table tab1 from databse project. I would like to get the time , user etc who dropped this table?

**EDIT**

I have checked for the audit logs in the following , but couldn't find the one which i was looking for in any of the below :

1. Hive Metastore - TBLS, DBS , TRANSACTION tables
2. Hive installation log directory.
3. Hive query log path as mentioned in hive-site.xml - property - "hive.querylog.location"

The audit log would help me in doing the security level auditing.

Answer (score 1):

all the config related to login is here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted#GettingStarted-HiveLogging, it will give you the location of the logs, there you will find the info that you are looking for

Comment: The logs that are created doesnt have the proper audit logs. It has few details thats it. It doesnt have when a user created a tbale or when he deleted that table and created it back again, not at transactional level.